# excel adding 1 on all alphanumeric string

Tags: string, excel, sum, formula, alphanumeric

I need to make a new product code for 6000+ records. In order to do that fast and decipher it in the future, I need to put a formula from the old code to the new code.

sample codes:

```
yas111
bd224
sax112
sd00015
sp00114
```

If my formula is +1, the end result shoulb be:

```
zbt222   
ce335
tby223
te11126
tq11225
```

numbers will +1, and letters will increment to the next letter of the alphabet. 
I tried the substitute function, its working. but it cannot read both if there is a number that is already used. example:

```
Substitute(substitute(a1,"0","5"),"5","0")
```

It will only read 1.
result will be

```
0 = 0
5 = 0
```

but I'm trying to get this result:

```
0 = 5
5 = 0
```

Comment: How can you be sure that they won't collide with existing codes?

Comment: What would zzz999 be afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in pure excel formula will be in my opinion unmanageably complex.  The best way would be ti use a vba `UDF`

```
Function IncrCode(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim strOld As String, strNew As String
    Dim i As Long

    strOld = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
    strNew = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(strOld)
        strNew = strNew & Chr$(Asc(Mid$(strOld, i, 1)) + 1)
    Next
    IncrCode = strNew
End Function
```

Call it like this

```
=IncrCode(A1)
```

if `A1` = `yas111` result would be `zbt222`

Note that based on your question, all characters are incremented to the next ascii character, eg
`9` --> `:`
`z` --> `{`
`Z` --> `[`

Comment: Thanks, my bad.. 9 should be 0. maybe there should be exception for 9 and z. how would i do that?

Comment: Simply separate the `asc(...)` bit, test it for limit cases and return the required character.  Give it a go and post back if you get stuck

Comment: I don't know how to use vba udf. I'm not a programmer. I tried it but cannot figure it out.can you help me on that? or is it possible to for you to post a file here?

Comment: Working!! Thank you Chris Neilsen! I use substitute function for z and p

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a single character that will never be used.  Let's say that it's `&`.

Armed with this never-used character, you can then do it like this:

Change all of your Z's to &.
Change all of your Y's to Z.
Change all of your X's to Y.
Change all of your W's to X.
.
.  etc., etc.
.
Change all of your &'s to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But not working... When i assigned w to x, and x to y. result for that was w=y  x=y

Comment: You have to do it in the opposite order.  Once you change all Z's to &'s, you know there are no Z's.  So it is safe to change Y's to Z's.  Then there are no Y's, so you can change X's to Y's.  etc.  Once you are done, you can change those &'s that used to be Z's into whatever you actually wanted them to be.